# How to keep an anchor in the same state as its :hover state after a click?

Tags: css

I have specified the pseudo states `:hover` and `:active` for my links. On hover, the size of the anchor (`<a>`) increases. When I click on it, the `:active` state is activated.

But now, when the `:active` state's passed, the box returns to the origin, `a:link` state's size (dimensions) and because of the still-there mouseover, the `:hover` state is reactivated, again increasing the size.

This appears to be the default behaviour, but looks confusing:

- you hover over the link and it expands
- you click on it
- it shrinks for a moment
- it expands again

HTML

```
<div class="textPool">
<a href=""><p>Japan and Porn<span> Ban on Child Porn, Boku no Pico, and More</span></p></a>
<a href=""><p>Cool Japan and Her Creative Industries</p></a>
<a href=""><p>Death Note<span> The "Sequel" and the Mid-2007 Days</span></p></a>
<a href=""><p><span>Insight Into</span> Indian Anime Trends</p></a>
<a href=""><p><span>Quick</span> Anime Production Summary</p></a>
<a href=""><p>Hetalia</p></a>
<a href=""><p>Ace of Diamond</p></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.textPool {
    width: 300px;
    height: 460px;
}

.textPool a {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;    
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: blue;
    background: rgba(188,143,143,.8);

    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.textPool a:hover, .textPool a:focus, .textPool a:active {
    height: 100px;
    width: 290px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: navy;
}

.textPool a:active {
    background: rgba(188,143,143,1.0);
}

.textPool a p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 7px;
}

.textPool a p span {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
}

.textPool a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}

.textPool a:first-child {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's already fixed, but I would just write a rule so that the `:active` state retains the same width and height as the `:hover` state, like this:

```
.textPool a:hover, .textPool a:active {
    height: 100px;
    width: 290px;
}
```

If you use **Sass or Less** you could write the rule once and then import it.

Here's a **JSFiddle** for you to mess with: [jsfiddle.net/qfhnsy93/](http://jsfiddle.net/qfhnsy93/)

Comment: After the click, it remains expanded, even if not hovered.

Comment: Not for me. I don't see that action. What's your setup like? Also, it's unclear what action/animation you're looking for. Just my $0.02 here, but that animation looks dated & gaudy. Why don't you try for something a bit more modern & subtle anyways?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined increased value for width and height for :hover & :active state, make it same as :

```
width:200px; height:60px;
```